# SAS "CLI cursor extended fetch error: Numeric value out of range" while creating SAS dataset from Netezza Database

Tags: sql, sas, netezza, proc-sql

I am trying to create a SAS dataset in WORK from a Netezza table using Libname as follows:

```
libname  lib1
    netezza
    &_log_host
    server=&_server
    database=&_db
    schema=&_sch
;
```

and this is how I am processing the table:

```
data work.temp;
  set lib1.TBL_NAME(OBS=1);
RUN;
```

Libname gets assigned perfectly but when I run data step, it gives me following error:

```
ERROR: CLI cursor extended fetch error: Numeric value out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this occurs due to a column in Netezza being too long for a SAS numeric value. If you can figure out which column is causing the issue, you can read it as a character:

```
data work.temp;
  set lib1.tbl_name (obs=1 dbsastype=(mycolumn='CHAR(20)'));
run;
```

https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=n0v4ma1zb9lu99n1728j279rjcqi.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en